# How to check if An NSMutableArray Contains a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I am looking to check if NSMutableArray contains NSMutableDictionary, I know we can check for NSDictionary with

```
  [array indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dict];
```

But cannot work out how to check for NSMutableDictionary.
Any hint would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: `[array containsObject: dict];`

**EDIT:**

To get the Index you can use:

```
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObject: dict];
```

Comment: Thanks LoVo for your answer, It does the trick but I want to get the specific index of that NSMutableDictionary how it can be done ?

Comment: Thank you so much LoVo, You saved my day :) (y)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the objects in array with type of class.

```
    for (id object in mutableArray) {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
        // Mutable dictionary object
        NSInteger iIndex = [mutableArray indexOfObject:object];
    }
    else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        // Non-mutable dictionary object
        NSInteger iIndex = [mutableArray indexOfObject:object];
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`isKindOfClass` can also be useful here.
you can check a specific index this way

```
if ([[myArray objectAtIndex:myIndex] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
```

whereas this `NSDictionary` can be replaced by any `Data Type` that you want to compare with for example `NSArray`, `NSString` and others. I hope it helps you in distinguishing the types of data.